# Does a misdemeanor conviction prevent my entry into the UK?

Tags: visas, transit-visas

If I have a conviction for a misdemeanor, will I be banned from entering the UK?

Comment: Where is the conviction recorded?  Misdemeanor means different things in different countries.

Comment: You also tagged your question with 'transit visa' so please add clarification by indicating your nationality and what type of entry to the UK you seek. You can do this, as well as respond to @Johns-305, by using the Edit button to add the details to your question.

Comment: No, not necessarily banned and perhaps not necessarily a problem. But nothing can be said without knowing your nationality, offence, custodial sentence, and country of offence.  We have to therefore mark this question as 'unclear'.  Use the edit button http://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/89773/edit to edit your question and then the 'reopen' button so we can get to work on it.